# Google chrome not obeying z-index when inside a fixed element.

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, z-index

I am setting up an interface for a social network, however, I am having an issue with z-index in google chrome. It seems to work as expected in safari, firefox and internet explorer.

See my layout on the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KV5nw/1/

The side bar should be fixed to the left of screen and the grey avatar should be above the dark grey block at the top.

If #sidebar has position fixed applied then #user_avatar's z-index is ignored.
If you set #sidebar's position to relative or absolute then #user_avatar's z-index is fine.

```
#sidebar{
  width:inherit;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
}
#user_avatar{
  margin:0 auto;
  width:120px;
  height: 120px;
  border:4px solid white;
  background-color: #555;
  display: block;
  margin-top:-100px;
  position: relative;
  z-index:501;
}
```

I am on google chrome version: Version 32.0.1700.107

Any advice?

Comment: I would like that the Red username block goes under the grey block and the avatar goes over.

I dont know if this is possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that Chrome creates a new [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) for elements that don't have a `z-index` set (default is auto). So your sidebar has a `z-index` of 0 which makes it (and all of its childrens) disappear since you've specified a higher z-index for your `#top` container.

To solve the problem, give the sidebar a `z-index` higher than the one from `#top`:

```
#sidebar{
    width:inherit;
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    z-index: 501;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KV5nw/2/)

Comment: Thanks very much. This helped me understand the situation.

However I realize I would want that only the avatar is above the grey block and the red username block is under the grey block.

http://jsfiddle.net/KV5nw/4/

In this js fiddle you can see the red block goes over the grey block.

Is what I want to achieve possible like this?

Comment: @k.ueckermann Unfortunately that's not possible with CSS. But you could change the position of `#user_avatar` inside the html structure with JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for the help! I think I found a way to restructure the interface now that will solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

`#user_avatar` and `#top` must be place at one level on DOM for normal `z-index`. Now parent of `#user_avatar` (`#sidebar`) has `z-index:0` and z-index of `#user_avatar` working only inside `#sidebar`. Add to parent of `#user_avatar` (`#sidebar`) `z-index:501` or replace `#user_avatar`

Answer (score 0):

Set the z-index for the fixed element too. 
I mean:

```
#sidebar{
  width:inherit;
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index: 501;

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solve a similar probleme by changing the **position** on sideBar from fixed to **absolute**